# Vertical scrollbar affects layout in browser

Tags: html, css, web, browser

I noticed that the same UI elements (such as a vertically-centered horizontal menu) in a browser are rendered in slightly different positions depending on the absence or presence of vertical scrollbars.

What are some current de facto solutions for ensuring same-positioning rendering despite the presence of vertical scrollbars?

Comment: The "simplest" though probably not the most visually appealing way is to have the scrollbars always visible. `body{overflow:scroll;}`

Comment: One solution is to not specify any widths or horizontal margins in percentages.

Comment: The "smart" way could be to create custom scrollbars (that do not interfere with the element width)